# How Do I remember window sizes for KDE/X11 applications

Tags: qt, resize, window, storage

Is there some kind of standard where to store the window size to when the application closes and where to load it from when the application starts? I'm wondering how I should store width&height parameters for a `Qt` application I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

OS X has [defaults system](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) but for Linux I'm not aware of any persistent or dynamic store (e.g. [scutil](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html)) like that.

Freedesktop.org has [config-data-dir](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) but not sure entirely its just specification of location or the format too.

Linux usually store its stuff in [config files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file), so my only suggestion is to create your config file (XML, INI or JSON formatted) in `~/.config/appname/settings.xml` and write data to it while closing application and read data while opening. 
So best to access configuration file is using [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) API